# Opening file manager from terminal, without annoying error message

Tags: file-manager, dolphin

Say that I work in terminal and I want to open with a terminal command the file manager. I read online that the way to do so is running `dolphin .` and it opens the file manager at the current location. So far no issues achieving this but I get the following in the terminal `Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  PlacesView(0x55bcca2f9840)  index: 8 KSambaShare: Could not find smb.conf!` which I don't know if it is good or bad or how to make it go away. Any suggestions on what is it, why I get it and how to make it go away?